# Build a method to delete a resource using Jena API

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology

I have created a method to delete resources - I hope the below code is correct.... but it deletes only one statement.

```java
public void deleteResource(String resourceName) {
    OntResource resource = om.getOntResource(ns + resourceName);    

    Statement rstm = om.createStatement(resource,null,(RDFNode)null);
    om.remove(rstm);
    return;     
}
```

How can I remove all the statements of the resource?

Answer (score 3):

You're mostly there:

```java
public static void deleteResource(Model model, Resource resource) {
    // remove statements where resource is subject
    model.removeAll(resource, null, (RDFNode) null);
    // remove statements where resource is object
    model.removeAll(null, null, resource);
}
```

Comment: Thank you...

I thought statement should be created to remove resource.

Answer (score 2):

This is already in in the API: [OntResource.remove()](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#remove%28%29)

Comment: Dead link; seems to have moved to: [org.apache.jena.ontology.OntResource.remove()](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#remove--)